# Why will Jquery Not Select the value of my input ?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap collapsable accordion AND BS collapsable panel.

When I try to grab the value of #test, Jquery will see the value in the accordion section. However, when I try to grab the value from the collapsable panel section JQuery will not see it even though the id is the same in both.  I am terrible at JS, however I had always believed that JQuery will grab every selector that matches ?

Accordion Section

```
<div class=" form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-2  col-md-2">{!! Form::label('company_name', 'Company Name:') !!}</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">{!! Form::text('company_name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Optional']) !!}</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">{!! Form::label('co_telephone', ' Company Telephone:') !!}</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">{!! Form::text('co_telephone', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'test' 'placeholder'=>'Optional']) !!}</div>
                    </div>
```

Collapsable Panel Section:

```
 <div>{!! Form::label('roofing1', 'Roofing Material:') !!}</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">{!! Form::select('product_code[0]',$roofing,null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'None']) !!}</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2  col-md-2">{!! Form::label('roofing_req1', 'Requirements:') !!}</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">{!! Form::text('quantity[0]',null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'test']) !!}</div>
```

Comment: selector `#id` only grabs the first matched element, you should use `.class` selector instead

Comment: *"..id is the same in both"* <- and that's an error